# Using fgets in combination with strtok to transform input to tokens

Tags: c, stdin, fgets, strtok

I am reading input from different text files. These text files are integers that are either separated by a space, a new line, or a combination of spaces and new lines. I want to convert these strings to integers, and use these integers for a sorting algorithm.

```
char *line = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
char *token;

struct list* l = list_init();

while (fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, stdin)) {
    token = strtok(buf," \n");
    printf("%s", token);
}

list_cleanup(l);

return 0;
```

What is wrong with this, it that it just prints the first element of each line. It doesn't handle multiple elements per line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `buf` or `line`?

Comment: Sorry, this was not clear. 

buf is the input. Line is where I want to store the tokens

Comment: That's why it's so important to create a [mcve] to show us. Please edit your question to include one. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `man 3 strtok` maybe? "the  `strtok()`  function breaks a string into a sequence of zero or more
       nonempty tokens.  On the first call  to  `strtok()`,  the  string  to  be
       parsed should be specified in str.  In each subsequent call that should
       parse the same string, str must be `NULL`.". I don't see a loop for `strtok()` results.

Comment: the first thing that is wrong is the posted code does not compile!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have `loop` to process all the tokens. `strtok` will return `NULL` once all the tokens are over.

**Example:**

```
while (fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, stdin)) {
    token = strtok(buf," \n");

    while (token != NULL) { 
        printf("%s", token);
        token = strtok(NULL," \n");
    }
}
```